# Android Studio : Debug info can be unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am having this weird problem with my android studio which is not letting me attach the debugger to my device. The error says :

> Debug info can be unavailable. Please close other applications using ADB.

I've checked and verified that no other application is using adb. Tried killing the adb server and restarting it again. Also tried restarting android studio.

From command line, adb works fine.

> Android Studio Version : 3.0.1

Have been trying to solve this for 4 hours now. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It has been 4 years since the question was asked so I assume it was solved for you but for others:

Just giong to your phone's Settings -> Developer options and turning off and on `USB Debugging` should solve the issue.